# Pick random value from string array

Tags: vba, excel

How do I make the following code input either "Jack" or "John" randomly in cell `A1`? Currently, the result is always "2":

```
Sub RandomNames ()

Dim UserNames(1 To 2) As String

UserNames(1) = "Jack"
UserNames(2) = "John"

Range("A1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(LBound(UserNames), UBound(UserNames))

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, just a typo.

Comment: With your code now, without the typo, I get 1 and 2 pretty evenly.

Comment: BTW: the formula version: `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"Jack","John")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I needed names, not numbers.

Comment: I was just stating that your comment `Currently, the result is always "2"` is a little misleading as to your problem, as the code will return both `1` and `2`.

Comment: If your question is meant to say `Currently, the result is always just "1" or "2":`, please edit it to say that.  I read it as meaning that you always just got 2 and so I spent time looking at the `RandBetween` to see what was wrong before I noticed Scott's last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using randbetween on the array.

```
Range("A1").Value = UserNames(Application.RandBetween(LBound(UserNames), UBound(UserNames)))
```